# Leaking attributes of class to it's components

Tags: c++, oop, composition

I've got the following classes:

```
class A {
    // Whatever
};

class B {
    T attribute;
    A a;
};
```

Now suppose i have the following scenario:

```
A aX, aY;  
B bX, bY;
```

Now i can sort of "insert" `aX` or `aY` into `bX` or `bY`.

I would like for the objects of type A to know, what B they are in, or in other words, what is the "`attribute`" of their "superclass" B.

**Question:**

I would like to be able to move the objects of type A freely between their "superclasses" B and i need a **way to leak the attribute of B** to them dynamically at runtime, **so the objects of type A always know, what B they belong to** (or what is the attribute of B they are currently in).

What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: I've edited my answer and now it's bug-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful (pointer from the owner to the attribute, and the reverse):

```
class A;

class B {
    T attribute;
    A* a;
public:
   void setA(A* newA);
   T getAttribute() {return attribute;}
   void setAttribute() {/*some code*/}
};

class A {
   B* Owner;
   friend void B::setA(A* newA);
public:
    void setOwner(B* newOwner) {
        newOwner->setA(this);
    }
};

void B::setA(A* newA)
{
    A* tempA = this->a;
    B* tempB = newA->Owner;

    tempA->Owner = NULL;
    tempB->a = NULL;

    this->a = newA;
    newA->Owner = this;
}
```

**UPDATED:** Fixed a bug in cycle-pointing and cycle-calling, it could be solved only with a friend function.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could to is give `A` a pointer to it's `B` "parent":

```
class A {
public:
  A() : b_(0) {}
  explicit A(B* parent) : b_(parent) {}
private:
  B* b_;
};

class B {
  B() : a(this) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Define "B" class as interface. Make "getAttribute" method and set pointer of "B" to "A" class's instance. Now you can make child's of "B" class and add "A" classes to them and "A" class can always know attribute of "B".

```
class A 
{
    // Whatever
    B* pointerToB;
    void setB(B* b){ pointerToB = b; }
};

class B 
{
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
    void addA(A* a)
    {
       a->setB(this);
       this->a = *a;
    }  
    T getAttribute(){ return attribute; }
    T attribute;
    A a;
};

class BB : public B {} // define BB's someMethod version or more method's
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a pointer to `B` in `A` and use a reference to `A` in `B` to get waht you want directly from an `A` object:

```
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A {
    B *_b;
public:
    void setB(B *b) {
        _b = b;
    }

    B *getB() {
        return _b;
    }
};

class B {
    int _attribute;
    A &_a;
public:
    B(A& a, int attribute) : _attribute(attribute), _a(a) {
        _a.setB(this);
    }

    int getAttribute() {
        return _attribute;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    A a1;
    B b1(a1, 5);

    A a2;
    B b2(a2, 10);

    std::cout << a1.getB()->getAttribute() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a2.getB()->getAttribute() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
10
```